# Javascript if hasclass, alert "yes", else alert "no"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a multiple choice quiz where the answer is dragged and placed in a div. I want to make it so that if the correct answer is dragged into the div, then an alert will show up saying "yeah". If the wrong answer is dragged into the div, then the alert will say "noh".

I've tried using an if statement with the condition "hasClass". With the correct answer having the right class. Here is my code:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".ui-widget-content").draggable();
  $(".ui-widget-content2").draggable();
  $("#droppable").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      if ($("div").hasClass("ui-widget-content") === true) {
        alert("Yeah");
      } else {
        alert("noh");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>hello <span id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header"><span></span>
  </span>thank you</p>

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>vrother</p>
</div>

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content2">
  <p>sister</p>
</div>

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>dude</p>
</div>
```

Currently, the if part works (the alert says yeah when the correct answer is dragged). But when the wrong answer is dragged onto the div, nothing happens. I believe there must be something wrong with my else condition.

Comment: `$( "div" )` will return an array of divs. Second, `id` should be unique

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you not targeting the `div` you dropped, try with:

```
if($(ui.draggable).hasClass("ui-widget-content") === true) {
    alert("Yeah");
} else {
    alert("noh");
}
```

**Demo**

```js
$(function() {
  $(".draggable").draggable();
  $("#droppable").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      if ($(ui.draggable).hasClass("ui-widget-content2")) {
        console.log("Yeah");
      } else {
        console.log("noh");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">



<div class="ui-widget-content draggable">
  <p>Drag me to my target</p>
</div>

<div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
  <p>Drop here</p>
</div>



<div class="ui-widget-content ui-widget-content2 draggable">
  <p>Drag me to my target ui-widget-content2</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for responding, however, this now makes the correct answeres alert "noh" and nothing is happening with the wrong answer div when it is dragged.

Comment: @JoshK Try and run the demo i provided.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from the fact that you have hardcoded a selector in your callback:

```
if($( "div" ).hasClass
```

Since your first div has the class, you will never enter the else statement.
You should define this selector dynamically:

```
if($(ui.draggable).hasClass
```

```js
$(function() {
  $(".ui-widget-content").draggable();
  $(".ui-widget-content2").draggable();
  $("#droppable").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      if ($(ui.draggable).hasClass("ui-widget-content") === true) {
        alert("Yeah");
      } else {
        alert("noh");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#droppable {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 15px;
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<p>hello <span id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header"><span></span>
  </span>thank you</p>

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>vrother</p>
</div>

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content2">
  <p>sister</p>
</div>

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>dude</p>
</div>
```